# Can we limit NUMBER of user accessing a weblogic application?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I got this message in my logs:

ERROR [PoolTcpEndpoint] Endpoint ServerSocket [addr=/0.0.0.0, port=0, localport=8080] ignored exception: java.net. SocketException: Too many open files
java.net. SocketException: Too many open files
       at java.net. PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(NWeblogic app is running. **One thouasand user can work with application. Other users cannot work with application**?
09:02:10,887 ERROR [PoolTcpEndpoint] Endpoint ServerSocket [addr=/0.0.0.0, port=0, localport=8080] ignored exception: java.net. SocketException: Too many open files
java.net. SocketException: Too many open files
       at java.net. PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
active Method)

I am not sure whether we have any such option to limit the number of user accessing any weblogic application..

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you get this error because the number of open files allowed for the user running the WebLogic process has not been tuned - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23104_01/sysreqs1213/sysrs.htm#CHDHHIBA

The maximum number of open files (including sockets!) was 1024 by default on older linux kernels.

The cleanest way to increase this is to create a new file for the user running WebLogic in  /etc/security/limits.d. If you are running a systemd distribution and starting WebLogic from a service file, add a LimitNOFILE=65535 or such there.